# Ideal size/datatype of TSQL column to store cookie information

Tags: sql-server-2008, cookies, sqldatatypes

We are reading information from cookie and storing the value of the cookie in a SQL Server  database. Currently we are using `varchar(max)` as the data type, however it feels as if we can do away with a smaller size datatype.

My question is what is the ideal datatype and size in SQL Server 2008 of storing cookie value, considering the client can utilize the max limit allowed of a cookie value ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, a cookie should be 4k or less in size - so a `varchar(4096)` should be plenty enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd base the decision on the answer to the following questions:

- What is the absolute maxiumum largest size (in bytes) that a cookie can be?
- No, really, think it through. What might some bozo developer out there saddle you with in a week, a year, three years?
- Might they ever contain unicode characters? Binary data?
- Is it acceptable to ever store less than all the data in the cookie?
- If we choose to make the maximum size *stored* less than the maximum size possible, what data do we lose? Truncate the first or last N characters? Search for and dump specific contents (and you may still be over max storable size)?

The lack of any true control over the size of data you are required to store can be a killer.

Comment: All of the above points are valid and thats why it leads me to think varchar(max) could actually be safest

Comment: Varchar would be the wrong type if there's unicode or binary data, in which case use nvarchar(max) or varbinary(max). I'm not a cookie expert, is why I raise these points.

Comment: In my case the data in the cookie is integers and pipe "|" signs